# Keras fit_generator producing exception: output of generator should be a tuple(x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: [[[[ 0.86666673

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to build an autoencoder for non MNIST, non Imagenet data.  Using  https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html as my base.  However, am getting the following error.

```
**Exception: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: [[[[ 0.86666673  0.86666673  0.86666673 ...,  0.62352943  0.627451
     0.63137257]
   [ 0.86666673  0.86666673  0.86666673 ...,  0.63137257  0.627451
     0.627451  ]
   [ 0.86666673  0.86666673  0.86666673 ...,  0.63137257  0.627451
     0.62352943]
   ...,**
```

Since this is an autoencoder, in my datagenerator, used class mode=None.  My code is as follows.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D,   UpSampling2D,Activation, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.models import Model,Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 
import numpy as np
import os
import h5py


img_width=140 
img_height=140
train_data_dir=r'SitePhotos\train'
valid_data_dir=r'SitePhotos\validation'
input_img = Input(batch_shape=(32,3, img_width, img_width))

x = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (8, 4, 4) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, activation='sigmoid', border_mode='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mse')



valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=True)


valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        valid_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=True)

autoencoder.fit_generator(train_generator,
                nb_epoch=50,                
                validation_data=valid_generator,
                samples_per_epoch=113,
                nb_val_samples=32
                )
```

Comment: Can you check what is the dimension order of Keras? If you are using linux, the configuration file is at `~/.keras/keras.json`

Comment: it is 'th'.  Since I am using a windows PC, theano is the only option for me

Answer (score 1):

The real solution lies in this Keras issue apparently by @skottapa.

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4260

rodgzilla provided an updated ImageDataGenerator that adds a class_mode='input' that solves the problem.

The nice thing is that you can backport the modification to older Keras versions. A slightly modified image module can be downloaded here:

https://gist.github.com/gsdefender/293db0987a800cf1b103b7777966f8af